# Angular2 how to inject parent component into directive only if it's there?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have a select-all directive for my custom table component. I'd like a user of my directive to be able to instantiate it in two ways:

1:

```
<my-custom-table>
    <input type="checkbox" my-select-all-directive/>
</my-custom-table>
```

2:

```
<input type="checkbox" [table]="myTableRef" my-select-all-directive/>
<my-custom-table #myTableRef></my-custom-table>
```

I was able to get the first way working through the use of Host, Inject, and forwardRef in my directive's constructor:

```
constructor(@Host() @Inject(forwardRef(() => MyCustomTableComponent)) table?: MyCustomTableComponent) {
    this.table = table; //later I can call this.table.selectAll();
}
```

But when I instantiate it the second way, I get an exception that complains that there is no provider for MyCustomTableComponent, presumably because MyCustomTableComponent isn't the parent in the second way of instantiation, so Host and forwardRef return nothing...

How can I make that parameter optional? So my directive uses its parent or grandparent MyCustomTableComponent if it exists,  or otherwise uses whatever table is passed to it as input...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a dependency optional using the `@Optional()` decorator:

```
constructor(@Optional() @Host() @Inject(forwardRef(() => MyCustomTableComponent)) table?: MyCustomTableComponent) {
    this.table = table; //later I can call this.table.selectAll();
}
```

Comment: could loading a component into a directive cause the directive or component to initialize/load multiple times?

Comment: With "loading" do you mean "inject"? No, only existing component instances are injected. Don't list components in `providers: [...]`. That can cause that but usually makes no sense.

Comment: No, my concern was that I might be initializing the component multiple times when the directive used methods off of the component.  That ended up not being the case.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer why we need the forwardRef in this case?

Comment: You might not need it. I just copied the code from the question and added `@Optional()`. For example if you have the code for the parent component in the same file below the component where you want to inject it, then you'd need `@forwardRef(...)`.