# Angular 2 - Restrict Component to specific parent Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is is possible in Angular 2 to restrict a `Component` only to a specific parent element on a page. In other words, only allow a `Component` on a page if a certain parent element exists. Use case:

**should be possible**:

```
<parent>
  <child></child>
</parent>
```

**should not be possible** (has no `<parent>` tag as a parent)

```
<child></child>
```

I need the parent `Component` to transclude and the `<child>` tag is optional, so I **can't** do:

```
@Component({
  /*...*/
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `<child></child>`
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Inject the parent in the child, like that - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39083012/324224
If parent is not present, throw an exception or smth else to notify the developer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like that should do the trick.

#### Parent component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})

export class ParentComponent {

}
```

#### Child component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: ''
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(parent: ParentComponent){
    // will throw a no provider error if parent is not set
  }
}
```

then you can use your components like you want:

```html
<parent><child></child></parent> <!-- works -->
<child></child> <!-- fails -->
```

Note that when you inject the parent in the child, the child can actually be the grand-child without throwing an error.

Comment: child component still can be used anywhere

Comment: no, you get a "No provider for ParentComponent" error.

Comment: check my [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/e8o3kcCm62iNemTpS6FI?p=preview), I put a single `<child></child>` without parent, and an exception is thrown...

Comment: to be used anywhere you should mark the `ParentComponent` as `@Optional()` in child's constructor

Comment: there is a case where your approach won't work. `<parent><other-parent><child></child></other-parent></parent>` if child must be in directly under parent the code won't fail. see here https://plnkr.co/edit/PuxtjSxyBzKTN17n7zXS

Comment: I already stated this: "Note that when you inject the parent in the child, the child can actually be the grand-child without throwing an error." but maybe that was unclear

Comment: ah I didn't noticed

Answer (score 2):

A slight improvement over the accepted answer lets you throw a nicer error message by using the `Optional` decorator and checking for `null`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(@Optional() parent: ParentComponent){
    if (parent === null) 
      throw new Error("ChildComponent can only be used inside of ParentComponent")
  }
}
```