# How to only allow a child component to be added to a specific parent component

Tags: angular

Is there a way to only allow a child component to be added to a specific parent component?

For example, if I create a parent component called EuropeComponent and I create a child component called UnitedKingdomComponent, I want to keep it from being added to any other parent component.

```
<!-- Correct -->
<EuropeComponent>
    <UnitedKingdomComponent></UnitedKingdomComponent>
</EuropeComponent>

<!-- Incorrect -->
<NorthAmericaComponent>
    <UnitedKingdomComponent></UnitedKingdomComponent>
</NorthAmericanComponent>
```

I would like to make it so that there are no circumstances where the UnitedKingdomComponent can be added to an unintended parent component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Restrict Component to specific parent Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974808/angular-2-restrict-component-to-specific-parent-component)

Comment: @mbojko From my understanding, the accepted answer for that question seems to have an issue where the child component can still be added to a different parent component as long as the intended parent component is an ancestor of that parent component .e.g EuropeComponent > FranceComponent > UnitedKingdomComponent.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you mean by "allow" and what should be the consequences if the child is added to an invalid parent component.

But you could place your Components in different Modules. Create a Europe Module with EuropeComponent and UnitedKingdomComponent as well as another module with the NorthAmericaComponent.

Now, if I try to add UnitedKingdomComponent in NorthAmericaComponent, I get an error in VS Code ("UnitedKingdomComponent" is not a known element). I guess there will also be an error at runtime.

Comment: You can still write `<NorthAmericaComponent>
    <UnitedKingdomComponent></UnitedKingdomComponent>
</NorthAmericanComponent>` if you import both modules though

Comment: @LeBavarois If you expanded EuropeModule by adding another component like FranceComponent, couldn't you add UnitedKingdomComponent to FranceComponent as well as EuropeComponent?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. You just could not use it in NorthAmericaComponent (with the limitation mentioned by Gilsidoo in the first comment)