# Angular Create component that depends on another higher level component

Tags: angular, components

I would like to create angular component that can not be rendered unless wrapped in another higher level components. 
To understand this better here is an example (example comes from `angular material` structure of tabs):

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I want to create same structure where `mat-tab` will be my component that can not be rendered with out a `mat-tab-group` wrapping component.

I am looking through angular documentation but can not find relative information. 
Can any one help please?

Thank you!

Comment: Please checkout this link, Question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974808/angular-2-restrict-component-to-specific-parent-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Syed exactly what I was looking for.

[Angular 2 - Restrict Component to specific parent Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974808/angular-2-restrict-component-to-specific-parent-component)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Optional and Host to get the "mat-tab-group"

In your child

```
get hasParent()
{
    return this.hello!=null
}
constructor(@Optional() @Host() private hello:HelloComponent){}
```

You can use in child.component.ts

```
<ng-container *ngIf="hasParent">
....
</ng-container>
```

If you make public hello you can use in the .html(*) like

```
<h1 *ngIf="hasParent">Hello!, parent's name is {{hello.name}}</h1>
```

(*)If is private you can access to all the public properties in the child using `this.hello.oneProperty` or `this.hello.oneFunction()`
See [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y4oebx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts)