# Angular 10 Child Component only be used in Parent Component

Tags: angular, components, angular-components, angular10

I need to configuration on component to be used only inside another component.
How can I do that?

Components:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu[id]',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent {
    ...
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sub-menu[id]',
    templateUrl: './sub-menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sub-menu.component.scss']
})
export class SubMenuComponent {
    ...
}
```

**HTML**

The correct use MUST be only like that:

```
<app-menu>
    <app-sub-menu></app-sub-menu>
</app-menu>
```

I need to block this kind of use:

```
<div>
    <app-sub-menu></app-sub-menu>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you waiting for `id` at the selector ?
Remove it and it will work.
even in the `div`

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi to force the use of the ID attribute in my component tag. In my scenario, it's useful to do unit tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your child component's constructor inject parent component. and in html file use child component selector in parent component selector.

This may help you. [Angular 2 - Restrict Component to specific parent Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974808/angular-2-restrict-component-to-specific-parent-component).